# Colocar array de objetos no comboBox

Tags: java, swing

Tenho o seguinte método para adicionar objetos em um `JComboBox`:

```
public void PopulaCategoria() throws SQLException{
    for(Categoria categoria : caDAO.getCategorias()){
        comboCategoria.addItem(categoria);
    }              
}
```

Porém ele da erro no `comboCategoria.addItem(categoria);` dizendo que `Categoria` não pode ser convertido em `String`, porém eu já coloquei o método `toString()` dentro do meu model `Categoria`:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return this.nomCategoria;
}
```

Ele não deveria adicionar os objetos dentro do `JComboBox` e mostrar apenas o nome?

Comment: É Swing ou JavaFX?

Comment: Estou usando Swing

Answer (score 2):

Não é só porque há um método `toString()` que isso signifique que ele seria chamado automagicamente. Você deve chamá-lo:

```
public void PopulaCategoria() throws SQLException{
    for(Categoria categoria : caDAO.getCategorias()){
        comboCategoria.addItem(categoria.toString());
    }              
}
```

Há alguns lugares na API que até parece que ele seria chamado automagicamente. O que ocorre é que alguns métodos recebem como parâmetro o tipo `Object` (não é o caso desse `addItem`), E depois, dentro da implementação desse método, o `toString()` é chamado.

No caso, o tipo do parâmetro do `addItem` é `<E>`, ou seja é um método genérico. Se você tiver uma `JComboBox<String>`, então o tipo do parâmetro será `String`. Você poderá fazer a adição diretamente se tiver uma `JComboBox<Categoria>` ou uma `JComboBox<? super Categoria>`.

Comment: Então se eu quiser inserir um objeto no comboBox terei que usar outro método?

Comment: @EduardoBalestrin Onde e como essa `JComboBox` é declarada?

Comment: Anteriormente estava assim private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> comboCategoria; -> Agora que vi o String mudei para: private javax.swing.JComboBox<Categoria> comboCategoria;. Obrigado